# Adicionar valores de um array à uma variável vazia com psuh

Tags: javascript, foreach, parâmetros, variáveis-globais, array-push

No código abaixo eu gostaria de armazenar os valores deste `array` na variável vazia `var gorjetas = []`, utilizando o método `push`.

```
var item =  [589, 448, 
    697, 4568, 1487, 668, 478, 5387, 1147, 2235, 
    5578, 5693, 335, 114, 225, 356, 358, 774, 441, 
    325, 2254, 225, 220, 100, 89, 78, 558, 25]

var gorjetas = []

item.forEach(function (item) {
  if (item < 100) {
    console.log(item * 0.15);
  } else if (item > 100 && item <= 150) {
    console.log(item * 0.1);
  } else if (item > 150 && item <= 300) {
    console.log(item * 0.08);
  } else {
    item > 300;
    console.log(item * 0.05);
  }
});
```

Comment: já tentou fazer `gorjetas = item` ou `gorjetas.push(item)`?

Comment: O map retorna um novo array do mesmo tamanho, caso precise. ou só implementar o **push** com os valores ja incluído `gorjetas.push(item * 0.15);`

Comment: Resolvido!!!!
Obrigado!!!

Answer (score -1):

Olá, a cada if que entrar você quer adicionar o valor na variável gorjetas?

Se sim, a cada if você pode colocar um push, exemplo: `gorjetas.push(item * 0.15)`